# C# to Cassandra service with username and password

Tags: c#, service, cassandra, datastax

Cassandra is running as a service on a remote machine but in the same network. Also I created a .net program that communicates with the Cassandra environment.

I was able to communicate with Cassandra when it was NOT running as a service with the following connection string:

```
private void Connect()
    {
        cluster = Cluster.Builder().WithCredentials(username, password).AddContactPoint("192.168.30.104").Build();
        session = cluster.Connect("core_meter");
    }
```

But when I try to connect to Cassandra when its running as a service I get the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'Cassandra.NoHostAvailableException' occurred in Cassandra.dll
>
> Additional information: None of the hosts tried for query are available (tried: 192.168.30.104:9042)

I am not sure if I have to change anything in my .yaml file before I can approach a service with username and password. 
here is the yaml file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wbrexlarkjrvlrm/cassandra.yaml?dl=0

edit: When i communicate with the service WITHOUT a username and password I can communicate with the service (I can always communicate with the execution through command prompt) but when I use a username and password it does not work anymore.

Comment: Check "Resource Monitor" for "Listening Ports" on windows Or "netstat -tnlp" on Linux for both instances and check to see 9042 is exposed on localhost or 192.168.30.104

Comment: If I'm correct, in the case where you are seeing this error, you have the Cassandra running on localhost:9042

Comment: @Sreekar I opened the 9042 ports on the server. Also, i am able to communicate with the service if it does not have a username or password. Sorry, did not notice you are the same guy as below ;)

Comment: NoHostAvailableException have a property called `InnerErrors` that contains the error for each host attempted, check that.

Comment: @jorgebg Yes i did that, the inner exception = null

Comment: Not `InnerException` but `InnerErrors`...

Comment: @jorgebg Ah yes, my bad. InnerError = Username and/or password are incorrect.
(but they are not).

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that your service and the single executable are using *different* yaml configuration files. Check your environment variables and your `cassandra-env.sh` files. Also have a look at [DataStax documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/tools/toolsCUtility_t.html).

Comment: No, cause when i use the service (without username and password) i can communicate with it and insert rows in my database. I can see those rows with the single executable. They are the same.

Comment: @Proliges what xmas79 said is right. You have problem in exposing the service properly over network, that seems to be happening because it's using a different version of yaml file which has listen_address as localhost. Data might seem proper because data directory and commit log is same for both service and single executable

Comment: Okay, then where can I find this secret yaml file for the service? And why can I communicate with the service if I remove the username and password? And why is it that I had to change this .yaml file in order for the service to work (and not the other one)? It makes no sense to me that there would be another .yaml file set as localhost since I shouldn't be able to make a remote connection right? @Sreekar

Comment: @Proliges I'm a little confused. So your only problem is connecting remotely with username and password? In all other cases, including when you have used username and password locally, it worked?

Comment: @Sreekar Correct. I am able to communicate with the service when the service has NO username or password. I can insert data in the cassandra environment,read it, do with it whatever i want. I can also see this data when i run Cassandra in command prompt instead of a service. 

Also i can communicate with the Cassandra environment when I run it in command prompt, and have a username and password. But when its a service and it has (the same) username and password. I can not communicate and i get the error stated in my question.

Comment: @Proliges I think this solves your issue. (But it's in Python) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21787950/how-to-pass-along-username-and-password-to-cassandra-in-python